# is it possible to create a new variable from a user-defined data type by "using" keyword?

Tags: c++, using, user-defined-types

I have the following:

```
class EventHandler {
    template <class T>
    using Handler = void(T::*)(Object* sender) ;
    template <class T>
    Handler<T> m_Handler;  // <===
public:
    template <class T>
    EventHandler(Handler<T> handler) : m_Handler(handler) {}
    // ....
   // ...
};
```

But this line `Handler<T> m_Handler;` occurs an error:
`error C3376: EventHandler::m_Handler: only static data member templates are allowed`.

**Is that mean that the "using" keyword can't create a user-defined datatype like "typedef"?**

Comment: The problem is not `using`, it's trying to make a template non-static member.

Comment: Perhaps `std::function<void(Object*)>` might be a better type for the `Handler` type-alias? No templates needed, and you can use any kind of callable object.

Answer (score 3):

This has nothing to do with the `using` keyword, whatsoever. The problematic declaration is:

```
template <class T> Handler<T> m_Handler;
```

It is immaterial where `Handler` came from.

This is attempting to declare a non-function class member named `m_Handler` ...that's a template. There's no such thing in C++. All class members must be specific, concrete types and not templates. You could declare a class member that's a template:

```
template<class T> class Handler {

  //...
};
```

That would be a member of this class. And then you can declare some specific instance of this template, as a class member:

```
Handler<int> m_Handler
```

But the shown code attempts to declare something that's both a template and some data member of the class. Something like this does not exist in C++.

Comment: But if I take that approach will encounter a problem somewhere else, because I declare something like this `EventHandler *OnClick = nullptr;` into some base classes that I can't determine the template datatype in this stage (I can't do this `EventHandler<Button> *OnClick = nullptr;` because "Button" is a base class). is there a way to solve that problem?

Comment: I was only giving an example that meant to illustrate the underlying concept, rather than suggesting any potential alternative. It is unclear what the original excerpt of shown code was trying to do, and this was meant only to explain the compilation error, and nothing else. It's unclear what you're asking, except to say, yes, `EventHandler` is a template, not a type, so this won't compile either, for the same reason. Perhaps explaining the larger problem, in a separate question, will be more helpful.

Answer (score 1):

If the class must hold a `Handler<T>` then the class must be templated:

```
template<class T>
class EventHandler {
    using Handler = void(T::*)(Object* sender);
    Handler<T> m_Handler;
public:
    EventHandler(Handler<T> handler) : m_Handler(handler) {}
    // ....
   // ...
};
```